# Laravel socialite config access type as offline in google login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Well i'm trying to implement in laravel 5.1 the login with google using socialite and i don´t have problems with the scopes but i need to implement the access_type  as offline, somebody know, how can i configure this in socialite for laravel?

this is my connection line

```
$scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

    ];
    return Socialize::driver('google')->scopes($scopes)->setAccessType('offline')->redirect();
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *literally* had this issue only yesterday when playing about with the Gmail API.

I assume you’re wanting to get a refresh token for an already authenticated user. I couldn’t find a way to do this natively in Socialite (I’m not sure where you’re getting an `setAccessType()` method from as it doesn’t exist in the the Google or abstract provider classes).

In the end, I just temporarily changed the string the `getAuthUrl()` method returned to tack the query string parameter on the end, went through the authentication process, then reverted the file (so as not to have Composer moan at me next time I updated).

It’s not an ideal solution, but hopefully it helps if you’re just wanting to re-authenticate yourself.

Comment: Does this english make any sense?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa Clearly does since it was marked as the correct answer. I also kinda hope I have a handle on the English language, being a native speaker of it since birth almost 34 years ago now.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe an update since this question was last answered; looks like Taylor added functionality to pass optional parameters. Call the `with` method with an associative array:

```
$scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
];
$parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];
return Socialite::driver('google')->scopes($scopes)->with($parameters)->redirect();
```

Comment: This only works on fresh logins. If your refresh_token comes back blank then add `"prompt" => "consent select_account"` to the parameters to force it to ask again.